# Is there a way to freeze training for weights, but not biases in PyTorch?

Tags: neural-networks, training, pytorch, weights, bias

I'm constructing a neural network where the weights of my first hidden layer (connected to the input) are all 1 (identity matrix), but the biases are variable.

Is there a way to "freeze" any updates/training to the weights in a specific layer, but continue to allow the biases in that specific layer to be updated?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-the-pytorch-freeze-network-in-some-layers-only-the-rest-of-the-training/7088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something link this

```
model.linear1.weight.requires_grad = False
model.linear1.bias.requires_grad = False
```

for the pytorch model with linear1 defined as:

```
self.linear1 = nn.Linear(5, 5)
```

as in [this](https://gist.github.com/L0SG/2f6d81e4ad119c4f798ab81fa8d62d3f) code snippet